# ValueError: Function does not reduce - for multiindex, but works fine for single index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a', 'b', 'b'], 'c2': [1, 2, 2], 'c3': [[100], [200], [100]]})
df
```

that is

```
   c1  c2     c3
0   a   1  [100]
1   b   2  [200]
2   b   2  [100]
```

Now when I try to concatenate column `c3` after grouping by on `c1`, I get desired result

```
In [40]: df.groupby('c1').agg({'c3': 'sum'})
Out[40]:
        c3
c1
a        [100]
b   [200, 100]
```

But if I try to groupby on both `c1` and `c2`, that is

```
df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).agg({'c3': 'sum'})
```

I get an error saying `ValueError: Function does not reduce`.
Why is it that?

Comment: Try upgrade pandas version, in `pandas 0.23.1` it working nice.

Comment: Thanks I was on `pandas 0.22.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas `0.23.1` it working nice, so it is bug in lower versions of pandas:

```
a =  df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).agg({'c3': 'sum'})
print(a)
               c3
c1 c2            
a  1        [100]
b  2   [200, 100]
```